# sp::SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sp, d) : Object length mismatch:

Tags: r, spatial, shapefile, terra

I have 2 shapefiles both have different number of rows and polygons mentioned below :-

nrow(shape1)
[1] 84172

> nrow(shape2)
> [1] 35283

i am doing terra::erase or raster::erase on that . but i am facing below issue . can anyone help me with same ?

code below

`erase <- terra::erase(shape1,shape2)`

error :-

```
     sp has 78871 Polygons objects, but d has 78794 rows
```

Comment: What are those shape object types and how are those loaded / processed? `terra::erase()` works fine with objects of different row counts, but expects  terra `SpatVector`s while  title and error seem to refer to `sp` object(s). Please consider including enough code to make this problem reproducible, you can use shapefile examples included in packages, i.e. `system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")` or `system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")`